# Cube in open subspace of R^n

Tags: real-analysis

Given is a open subspace $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

a) Prove that for every $a \in U$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that the cube $$V(a; \delta) := ]a_{1} - \delta, a_{1} + \delta [ \times ... \times ] a_{n} - \delta, a_{n} + \delta [ \space \space \subset \space U$$

b) Consider $\pi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\pi (x) = x_{1}$. Prove that the set $\pi (U)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

So I get the idea of both questions, but I am struggling with putting it on paper. This is what I am thinking:

a) Since $U$ is open there exists a $\delta_{1}$ such that $B(a; \delta_{1}) \subset U$. If you choose $\delta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\delta_{1}$ then $V(a; \delta) \subset B(a; \delta_{1}) \subset U$.

b) I made a drawing for this question, and it's fairly obvious since it is just a projection on $\mathbb{R}$. Since $x_{1} \in \space ]a_{1} - \delta, a_{1} + \delta [$, $\pi_{x}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Can someone help me mold my thoughts into a rigorous proof? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basic idea is right.

a) It is easier if you use the notation for the euclidian and maximum norm.

**Notation:**

Define $\|x\|_\infty=\max\{|x_i|~:~i=1,\ldots,n\}$, $\|x\|_2=\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i|^2\right)^{1/2}$ and $B_{\|\cdot\|}(a;r)=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^n~:~\|x-a\|<r\}$. Then you have $V(a;r)=B_{\|\cdot\|_\infty}(a;r)$ and $B(a;r)=B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(a;r)$.

Properties of the normes on $\mathbb{R}^N$:


Next you can check $\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\|x\|_2\leq \|x\|_\infty\leq \|x\|_2$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore $B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(a;r)\subseteq B_{\|\cdot\|_\infty}(a;r)\subseteq B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(a;\sqrt{n}r)$ for all $r>0$.

**Solution:**

For $a\in U$ you get $\delta>0$ such that $B(a;\delta)\subseteq U$. You are right to define $\delta_1=\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\delta$, which gives
$$
V(a;\delta_1)=B_{\|\cdot\|_\infty}(a;\delta_1)\subseteq B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(a;\sqrt{n}\delta_1)\subseteq B_{\|\cdot\|_2}(a;\delta)=B(a;\delta).
$$

b) You have to take a point $\alpha\in \pi(U)$ and find an open neighbourhood of $\alpha$ in $\pi(U)$. Since $\alpha\in \pi(U)$, there exists $a\in U$, such that $a_1=\pi(a)=\alpha$. From a) you get $\delta_1$, such that $V(a;\delta_1)\subseteq U$, which yields $\pi(V(a;\delta_1))\subset \pi(U)$. Because $V(a;\delta_1)$ is da rectangle, it is obvious, that $\pi(V(a;\delta_1))=]a_1-\delta_1,a_1+\delta_1[=]\alpha-\delta_1,\alpha+\delta_1[$, which is an open subset of $\pi(U)$. Therefore $\pi(U)$ is open.